# How to compress/decompress with TFDJSONDatasets in Delphi

Tags: json, rest, delphi, compression

New REST application is created with Delphi Wizard. Between client and server data is transferred as TFDJSONDataSets. My idea is to compress TFDAdaptedDataSet(FDTable1) before it is transferred to ListAdd() procedure.

```
// Server side:
function TServerMethodsMain.GetDataSetRecords(const ADataInfo: String): TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  // ... some codes here to find dataset according to ADataInfo
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, 'Table1', TFDAdaptedDataSet(FDTable1));
end;

// Client side:
procedure udxGetData(ADataSet: TFDDataSet; ADataInfo: String);
var
  LDataSetList: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  ADataSet.Close;
  LDataSetList := ClientModuleMain.ServerMethodsMainClient.GetDataSetRecords(ADataInfo);
  ADataSet.Data := TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(LDataSetList, 0);
  ADataSet.Open;
end;
```

Did research in Google but can't find clue related to this kind of connection. Could anyone give me any tips, how to compress and decompress TFDJSONDataSets while sending it from server to client? I am creating my application based on these codes.
Thanks.

Comment: There is a property `Filter` on client side and server side that you can add ZLibCompression too which should provide what you need

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I will try what you advised. By the way, do you have any sample code about this to give me some clues?

Comment: As far as I know TFDJSONDataSets is already zipped in transmission.

Comment: I am still struggling to find Filter property.
Thanks to Dustypup. I will do a test to compare data transmission between TFDJSON transferring and Firebird DLL directly connection.

Comment: @Jason: do you mind to show me several pieces of code using Filter property you mentioned? I still can't find FIlter Property somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: On the server side, there's a `Filters` property in the TDSHTTPWebDispatcher.  On the client side, in TSQLConnection, there's a Filters property in the Datasnap driver

Comment: @Jason: Thank you so much, Jason! I am using C/S application template,  not B/S structure. I am not sure if TDSHTTPWebDispatcher can be used in my application.